# conditional sentence in the past

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

Suppose that I have a friend which I miss him very much and I am waiting for his call.

10 days later I see him in the university and I want to tell him that if he had known, how happy I would be by his calling, he would have called me(perhaps my sentence is grammatically wrong). so what is the sentence I should say?

is this correct?

If you had known how happy I would be, you would have called me.

and if it is correct why we use "you would have called me"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You would have called me** is the correct tense.

However, it seems strange to say *you would have called me* as if you are in a position to understand what he would have done.

Instead, you would normally rephrase such a sentence so that the main subject and verb is yourself:

> If you had known how happy I would be, **I'm sure** you would have called me.

Comment: why not  If you had known how happy I  would have been , I'm sure you would have called me not conditionnal but past conditionnal  because  the event  is  not  possible anymore

Comment: Yes, that also works. The subtle difference there is that, in that version, the happiness would have been fleeting rather than (possibly) continuing for more time.